# I have a qustion about empty EnumSets. I tried the .noneOf() method but i always get the "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" error

Tags: enums, enumset

This is a early construct of my class:

```
public class Player {
    public enum Tech {
        NONE(EnumSet.noneOf(Tech.class)),
        VEGETATION(EnumSet.of(NONE)),
        LIVESTOCK(EnumSet.of(NONE)),
        STRAWBERRIES(EnumSet.of(VEGETATION)),
        BIODOME(EnumSet.of(STRAWBERRIES)),
        BIOMASS(EnumSet.of(VEGETATION, LIVESTOCK));

        private final Set<Tech> prerequisites;

        Tech(Set<Tech> prerequisites) {
            this.prerequisites = prerequisites;
        }
    }
    private Set<Tech> techsKnown;

    public Player() {
        techsKnown = EnumSet.of(Tech.NONE);
    }
}
```

I want NONE to have an empty Set. What would be the best way?

Comment: Can you share your stacktrace?

Comment: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at Player.<init>(Player.java:21)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(NativeMethod)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:746)

Comment: i couldnt post the full stacktrace. For the full stacktrace you may copy paste the code and execute it